# jupyter notebook can not start

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I usually command with 'jupyter notebook' to start the jupyter notebook .

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/jake/venv/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 8, in 
>       sys.exit(main())   File "/home/jake/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py",
>   line 268, in launch_instance
>       return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/jake/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
>   line 663, in launch_instance
>       app.initialize(argv)   File "",
>   line 2, in initialize   File
>   "/home/jake/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
>   line 87, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/jake/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py",
>   line 1720, in initialize
>       self.init_webapp()   File "/home/jake/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py",
>   line 1482, in init_webapp
>       self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)   File "/home/jake/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py",
>   line 151, in listen
>       sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)   File "/home/jake/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line
>   174, in bind_sockets
>       sock.bind(sockaddr) OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

but this message is showed up

Comment: Are you working with virtual environments? Anaconda? Venv? Be more specific on what you are using and the general environment of your system, reading the error message only does not help, too generic imho. Add more specs and the community will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to /etc/hosts and check that the local host has the ip 127.0.0.1

How to go to the hosts file? If you are using Linux, open up terminal, type

```
cd /etc/
```

Then type

```
cat hosts
```

This will display the contents in hosts. Now you will see localhosts there. Change its value to 127.0.0.1 if it already isn't. And that should get your notebook running.

If you find that localhost is already 127.0.0.1, then try the command in your terminal:

```
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```

to run the jupyter notebook.

The second one is an immediate fix, but every time you want to start jupyter notebook, you will have to provide those two arguments. On the other hand, the first one is a permanent fix (recommended) and you just have to type "jupyter notebook" the next time.

Comment: it happened when I set the c.NotebookApp.ip="192.168.0.5' or something else it does not happen before

Comment: Well, did the above solution fix your issue?